# Why is my motherboard not recognising my USB stick as bootable?

Tags: boot, bios, usb-flash-drive, uefi

I created an USB flash drive with openmediavault v6 (not the installer, I mean I put the system on it).

I can use this flash drive to run OMV on the machine (a PC with a Gigabyte motherboard). I can access it via web GUI and also SSH.

I did this also with a second machine, an old Acer laptop. The laptop also boots fine into OMV and runs it.

However, when I use the flash drive on my ASRock motherboard which is running OMV4 from an SSD, the flash drive is not bootable.

**The flash drive is recognised in BIOS/UEFI settings** and I can put it first in the booting order. The drive actually appears twice, once as USB and once as UEFI USB. Maybe this is due to the drive having two partitions. I put both entries before all others. I also disabled the HDD drive totally, just to make sure.

The UEFI/BIOS has secure boot disabled, it has fast boot disabled. I can not see any other option that relates to UEFI or legacy mode. It is a pretty advanced board with a lot of tweaking options for the CPU (which I don't use at all). I will add more information the next time. (Normally, I access it headlessly. Attaching a monitor is not so easy.)

I might think that the flash drive is maybe in a legacy mode and the other motherboards recognise this but the ASRock does not. Might this be the case? I also tried with other flash drives, btw.

Comment: If your motherboard doesn’t support Legacy mode there isn’t anything you can do except make the installation media support UEFI mode

Comment: Thanks! I never thought of the motherboard not beeing able to read legacy. Also, since it detects the USB as `UEFI` I thought the flash drive is `UEFI`. But it's probably not the case.